# Load font via Firebase CDN

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am trying to load a font via Firebase (at `cdn.domain.co.uk`) but Chrome blocks the response due to `CORS` and gives the following error:

`Font from origin 'https://cdn.domain.co.uk' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://domain.co.uk' is therefore not allowed access.`

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 4):

Note to anybody who is also having this problem: **read the documentation**!

Apply the following to your `firebase.json` and change the value accordingly.

```
"headers": [ {
    "source" : "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
    "headers" : [ {
        "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "value" : "*"
    } ]
} ]
```

Full documentation available at Firebase: https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/full-config.html

Comment: Good to hear that you found a solution. A link to said documentation would be nice.